x86-64: Effective address' index is 0, unexpected offset
In an attempt to implement arrays in my programming language that compiles to assembly, I am struggling with expressions like array[0]. I have tested other indices like 1, 2, etc. and they work, but array[0] always returns 0, no matter what value is actually stored there in the array.
Assuming an array has these elements: [85, 15, 76, 58, 17], then element 0 should be 85.
Here is the code my compiler generates, can you see what is wrong with this?
.text
.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
  .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  call usr_main
  mov %rax, %rdi
  movq $60, %rax
  syscall
  movq %rbp, %rsp
  pop %rbp
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
.size main, .-main
.type usr_main, @function

usr_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    push %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    # define array
    movq $85, -8(%rbp)
    movq $15, -16(%rbp)
    movq $76, -24(%rbp)
    movq $58, -32(%rbp)
    movq $17, -40(%rbp)
    push $0 # an "offset", based on the size of other defined arrays (there are none)
    # Evaluate computed array expr (index expr)
    # IndexExpr Step 1: Evaluate offset of array
    # find "offset"
    movq (%rsp), %rdx
    # IndexExpr Step 2: Evaluate computed expr (the index)
    movq $0, %rbx # index of 0
    # IndexExpr Step 3: Do some nerd stuff for %rbp offset
    add %rdx, %rbx
    neg %rbx
    # IndexExpr Step 4: Evaluate offset from %rbp and return the expr
    movq -8(%rbp, %rbx, 8), %rax
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
    .size usr_main, .-usr_main

I have tried changing the offset in the effective address -8 to other values, however each time array[0] always returns 0.
I have also tried incrementing %rbx before the effective address and setting the offset to 0, with no luck.

That's interesting, storing arrays backward in memory is an unusual choice, though should still work (as long as you're not expecting traditional language interop).  Also let's note that you're pushing $0 and while using top of stack, never popping that entry, so that may mess up were some other code following.

Pushing 0 was defining a "variable", as in the compiler it stores the stack size and knows where it is at all times. As for pushing backwards, I never knew I was doing it wrong. I also assume that %rbp and %rsp are different, as the "variable" was stored on %rsp and the array on %rbp. I could be totally wrong, though.

push $0 will overwrite the first array element because you have not allocated the memory for the array. That is fine as long as it fits into the red zone but does not work together with your push.  A possible fix is to do sub rsp, 40. PS: learn to use a debugger.

(rbp-16) < (rbp-8).  So, the 2nd element (to rbp-16) is going to a lower memory address than the 1st element (to rbp-8).  The array elements are being store backwards in memory order.  Could make a few things difficult.  The negation you're doing is for backwards indexing — there should be a subtraction somewhere, but that's in allocation (as Jester says), not indexing.

Also for expression evaluation, should probably pop what you push, at some point that may interfere with some other expressions & statements.  One example, if you do some indexing 10 times within the body of a loop and that loop runs 1 million times, you'll have 80 million extra bytes on the stack, which is maybe ok, and maybe not.

Thanks to Jester for the solution. What I needed to do was add sub $40, %rbp before pushing individual array elements. Thank you to those who helped!
